# SQL SERVER 2012 xp_cmdshell path not found

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I wanted to read a simple txt file with one row so I created this procedure but it puts out path not found as error message.

What could the problem be?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[readFile] 
    (@Path  VARCHAR(500))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(255)
    --SET @Path = ISNULL(@Path,'C:\Users\Maga\test.txt') 

    SET @Command = 'type ' + @Path
    PRINT  @Command

    INSERT INTO SimpleText 
        EXEC xp_cmdshell @Command

    IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM SimpleText;
        END

END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing file path without double quote. you need pass that in double quote.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[readFile] 
    (@Path  VARCHAR(500))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Command VARCHAR(255)
    --SET @Path = ISNULL(@Path,'C:\Users\Maga\test.txt') 

    SET @Command = 'type "' + @Path +'"'
    PRINT  @Command

    INSERT INTO SimpleText 
        EXEC xp_cmdshell @Command

    IF @@ROWCOUNT <> 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM SimpleText;
        END

END
```